# jQuery `submit` method ignores POST sends with GET. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, zend-framework

I have a form like this.

```
<form id="hiddenForm" method="post" action="/my-controller/my-action/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenFormInput" name="HiddenFormInput">
</form>
```

which is produced by a web page accessible through `https://[my-server]/my-controller/my-action/`, which is also the action the form points to.

On the server side, I differentiate between `GET` and `POST` requests. Either the page is shown plainly (`GET`) or some results are shown depending on the form's values (`POST`).

When I use jQuery to submit the form (I am NOT employing AJAX here, simply submitting the form), as in this snippet,

```
$("#hiddenForm").submit();
```

then jQuery seems to submit this form with `GET`, although it's clearly marked to be submitted with `POST`. Even an `alert($("#hiddenForm").attr("method"));` always yields `"post"`. However, this unwanted behaviour only occurs if the page has been loaded by a `GET`. If the page came by a `POST`, i.e. the form has already been submitted at least once, everything works just as expected.

**Update**

The problem was a plain old `preventDefault()` one. The button that triggered the submit had a functionality of its own. It was a hyperlink. So I had this chain of actions.

1. Hyperlink to `https://[my-server]/my-controller/my-action/#`
2. Submit form with action `https://[my-server]/my-controller/my-action/`.

Of course that would result in a `GET` call without the form being submitted. Once I was on the page `https://[my-server]/my-controller/my-action/#` the hyperlink lost it's functionality. That's why the second try always worked because the chain of actions was reduced to the submission of the form.

1. <strike>Hyperlink to `https://[my-server]/my-controller/my-action/#`</strike> (no effect because already there)
2. Submit form with action `https://[my-server]/my-controller/my-action/`.

Then it worked of course.

Comment: what does `document.getElementById("hiddenForm").submit();` do?

Comment: How do you know the page were submitted using `GET` method?

Comment: did you try adding `<input type="submit" />` element to your form?

Comment: I tested it, the submit method "POST" is used by jQuery.

Comment: As this seems to be of interest: If the page with the form in it is loaded for the first time, it is retrieved with a GET, since no form was submitted. Once the form has been submitted, the page loads again (it's itself the form action). I do the differentiation with `$this->getRequest()->isPost()` in the controller using Zend Framework.

Comment: [@Michał](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1995170/michal-rybak), yes I have tried adding the submit element. However, it doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for `preventDefault()`, happened to me too, need coffee. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, there is no bug, at least on the last version of jQuery 2.0.3, one can test with this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dosubmit').on('click',function(){
    $("#hiddenForm").submit();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//
if(count($_GET) > 0) {
  echo "<textarea style=\"width: 700px; height: 90px;\">
Submitted with method=GET: \$_GET:
";
  var_dump($_GET);
  echo "</textarea>";
}

if(count($_POST) > 0) {
echo "<textarea style=\"width: 700px; height: 90px;\">
Submitted with method=POST: \$_POST:
";
  var_dump($_POST);
  echo "</textarea>";
}
?>

<form id="hiddenForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" id="HiddenFormInput" name="HiddenFormInput" />
</form>

<div id="dosubmit" style="background-color: gold; width: 200px; cursor: pointer;">Click me to Do jQuery Submit</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When one clicks on gold background text, $("#hiddenForm").submit(); is used to submit the form.

Here is the output:

```
Submitted with method=POST: $_POST:
array(1) {
  ["HiddenFormInput"]=>
    string(0) ""
}
```

In your original form, no URL arguments are passed by the submitting, as only inputs with name attribute specified are submitted. So I added the attribute name="**HiddenFormInput**" for your hidden input.