# Jquery firts post form always do a get instead of post

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post, http-get

This is my code

```
$("#btnPrintSOI").click(function () {
...

jQuery('<form action="' + url + '" target="_blank"  method="post">' + inputs + '</form>').appendTo('body').submit();

});
```

The url and inputs variables are loaded dynamically,
First time always open a new window(this is normal because _blank) with the message:

```
<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>
```

After this all the time run perfect, doing a post instead a GET.

I need to make it work perfectly, any idea why this not work the first time I click on the button and work perfectly the following times I click?

Comment: would like to know if there are any other DOM elements in the code,may be loading of images or scripts taking time ?.

Comment: No, There aren't, I'm pretty sure of that

Comment: Check here...  See if you are in similar situation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219181/jquery-submit-method-ignores-post-sends-with-get-why     Add a preventdefault() right before you make the submit call if you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.
The problem was that the first request was managed by a login server, like SSO Provider, after login process succeeded, this server performed a redirect(GET) to the original post URL.
That I did was to enable the method on WebAPI to handle HttpPost and HttpGet Requests

PD: I will tag this question with .Net and C#, maybe could be usefull