# Why form submit sends get request not post request?

Tags: php, html, post, get

There are many articles for the same still and None of them working for me. 
This is the PHP code.

```
<?php
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && !empty($_POST['preview-form-comment'])){
            echo $_POST['preview-form-comment'];
            $_SESSION['currentcode']=$_POST['preview-form-comment'];
          }
    ?>
```

This is the form html code.

```
<form id="preview-form" method="POST">
            <textarea required class="codemirror-textarea" rows="100" name="preview-form-comment" id="preview-form-comment"><?php echo $comment ?></textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="button" id="preview-form-submit">Submit</button>
            <!-- <input type="submit" onclick="savedata();" id="preview-form-submit" value="Submit"> -->
          </form>
```

This is the script.

```
<script>
      $('#preview-form-submit').on('click',function(){
        savedata();
        $('#preview-form').submit();
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery \`submit\` method ignores POST sends with GET. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219181/jquery-submit-method-ignores-post-sends-with-get-why)

Comment: Your form is missing the action attribute

Answer (score 2):

Just tried this code and it's working.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['preview-form-comment'])){
    echo $_POST['preview-form-comment'];
    $_SESSION['currentcode']=$_POST['preview-form-comment'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="preview-form" method="POST">
    <textarea required class="codemirror-textarea" rows="3" name="preview-form-comment" id="preview-form-comment"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="preview-form-submit">Submit</button>
    <!-- <input type="submit" onclick="savedata();" id="preview-form-submit" value="Submit"> -->
</form>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $('#preview-form-submit').on('click',function(){
        $('#preview-form').submit();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Please try putting this in one simple .php file.

NOTE: I took out your `savedata();` function as you didn't post it. But feel free to add it to this post and I will change my code